# SQL Server: Can't figure out what join to use

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following tables:

PriceEntry

- CarTypeID
- PersonID
- priceDate
- priceValue

CarType

- ID
- CarName

Person

- ID
- Name

The result I'm trying to achieve is this one (get all person names):

> Thursday 28 June 2018 Andy        NULL    NULL
>
> Thursday 28 June 2018 Pete        Audi    5000
>
> Thursday 28 June 2018 Bart        Audi    10000

But what I have is:

> Thursday 28 June 2018 Pete        Audi    5000
>
> Thursday 28 June 2018 Bart        Audi    10000

This is my query:

```
SELECT (
  DATENAME(dw, CAST(DATEPART(m, priceDate) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(d, priceDate) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(yy, priceDate) AS VARCHAR))
 + ' '+ FORMAT(priceDate, 'dd MMMM yyyy') )as 'Entering Date', p.Name as 'Person Name', CarName as 'CarName' , REPLACE(ap.priceValue,'.',',') as 'Price'
FROM PriceEntry ap 
FULL JOIN CarType at 
ON ap.CarTypeID = at.id
FULL JOIN Person p 
ON ap.PersonId = p.ID 
order by priceDate desc
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

My data:

[image]

```
SELECT 
* from PriceEntry 
WHERE priceDate = '2018-07-09 00:00:00.000'

select count(*) as 'Person count' from person 

select count(*) as 'car count' from CarType
```

I only have 1 row for today returned using the query while i want the rows returned for today for all persons

Comment: TRY LEFT OUTER JOIN Person P

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server!!!  Which one is this???

Comment: won't LEFT JOIN return less rows than FULL JOIN?

Comment: i tried using left join too but without result (full join was my last resort before asking here)

Comment: FULL JOIN is All of LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN, so reducing FULL to LEFT will give no new rows.

Comment: so you have a price entry, and you have a person, but no car, but you want to see the price and name of person?  I suspect you've misinterpreted what you should see from the data - we need to see more about the data behind the results

Comment: I'm sure you've either got no 'andy' record, OR the query you actually have is INNER JOIN or JOIN

Comment: i have added my data (1 record for today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my suggestion for your query:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, priceDate) + ' '+ FORMAT(priceDate, 'dd MMMM yyyy') )as Entering_Date,
       p.Name as Person_Name,
       at.CarName as Car_Name,
       REPLACE(ap.priceValue, '.', ',') as Price
FROM Person p LEFT JOIN
     PriceEntry ap 
     ON ap.PersonId = p.ID LEFT JOIN
     CarType at 
     ON ap.CarTypeID = at.id
ORDER BY ap.priceDate DESC;
```

Notes:

- If you want all persons, then that should be the first join in the series of `left join`s.
- You don't need to construct a date from a date's date parts to extract the day of the week.  That logic is simplified.
- Single quotes should be used only for string and date constants.
- I added underscores to the column aliases so they do not need to be escaped.

EDIT:

Your query in the edited question is quite different from what you describe.  The solution is simply to put the condition in the appropriate `on` clause:

This is my suggestion for your query:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, priceDate) + ' '+ FORMAT(priceDate, 'dd MMMM yyyy') )as Entering_Date,
       p.Name as Person_Name,
       at.CarName as Car_Name,
       REPLACE(ap.priceValue, '.', ',') as Price
FROM Person p LEFT JOIN
     PriceEntry ap 
     ON ap.PersonId = p.ID and ap.priceDate = '2018-07-09 LEFT JOIN
     CarType at 
     ON ap.CarTypeID = at.id
ORDER BY ap.priceDate DESC;
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, sadly this doesn't work, i get the exact same rows returned as in my question

Comment: check the data, consider reducing the query to only join to 1 table etc - have you really got the 'ANdy' record?

Comment: yes, i have updated my question by adding the data. i have 1 priceEntry-record for today and 800+ persons but the query still only returns 1 row for today

Comment: @user3127554 . . . Your edit significantly changes the question.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: @user3127554 . . . This question is explicitly about getting all persons.  All dates would be a new question and should be asked as a new question, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

Almost there. You need to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT (
    DATENAME(dw, CAST(DATEPART(m, priceDate) AS VARCHAR) + '/' 
      + CAST(DATEPART(d, priceDate) AS VARCHAR) + '/' 
      + CAST(DATEPART(yy, priceDate) AS VARCHAR))
      + ' '+ FORMAT(priceDate, 'dd MMMM yyyy') )as 'Entering Date', 
    p.Name as 'Person Name', 
    CarName as 'CarName' , 
    REPLACE(ap.priceValue,'.',',') as 'Price'
  FROM PriceEntry ap 
  LEFT JOIN CarType at ON ap.CarTypeID = at.id -- LEFT JOIN here!
  LEFT JOIN Person p ON ap.PersonId = p.ID -- LEFT JOIN here!
  ORDER BY priceDate desc
```

Comment: "this doesn't work" is not an answer. What's wrong? An error, it shows the wrong rows?

Comment: sorry for not being specific, it shows the exact same result as in my question

Comment: I don't see how dropping FULL to LEFT would give more rows to be honest

Comment: impossible to have MORE rows than `FULL`

Comment: Yes, `FULL JOIN` should show everything already. Can you post the DDL to run it here locally?